# Setting a boolean attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery

I understand that jquery will allow you to modify attributes with the .attr() method. There are basically two methods:

```
$('#element').attr('attribute', 'value') // sets the attribute
var attribute = $('#element').attr('attribute') // gets the attribute
```

My question is, how do you set a boolean attribute such as 'checked' on a checkbox or 'multiple' on a select tag?

I've tried doing the following without success:

```
$('#element').attr('attribute', true)
$('#element').attr('attribute', '')
```

All of these add the attribute but usually like this `<tag attribute="attribute">`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using `.prop` to deal with `boolean` that is for supported attributes like `selected/disabled/checked` e.t.c

```
$('#element').prop('attribute', true);
```

from jQuery docs, (an example)

`elem.checked` returns `true` (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

`$(elem).prop("checked")` returns `true` (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

`elem.getAttribute("checked")` returns `"checked"` (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

`$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6)` returns `"checked"` (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

`$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6.1+)` returns `"checked"` (String) Will change with checkbox state

`$(elem).attr("checked")(pre-1.6)` returns `true` (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state

Comment: prop() sets the *property*, attr() sets the *attribute*. It is not always correct to "just use prop() instead".

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes are always string values.  If you indeed want to set something other than a string, then please consider using jQuery.data()

Comment: Not true in HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't have made that assumption... apologies

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in jQuery

```
jQuery('option').attr("selected", "");
```

or in JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector("option").setAttribute("selected", "");
```

It's just you need to pass an empty string to just set boolean attribute.