# Check box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSON data looks like this:

```
{"id":8,"userName":"gentelman","fullname":"Alexen","email":"alex@yahoo.com",
"mobile":"0060111434325","designation":null,"add_content":1,"edit_content":1,
"delete_content":1,"manage_user":1,"view_log":1}
```

I am trying to make checkbox `checked` when `add_content = 1`, else make it `unchecked`. Now it works only when I refresh page. I want to make it work without refreshing page. How to do that?

```
load: function (id) {
    var self = this;

    KeyWord.byId(
        id,
        function (data) {
            if (data.add_content == 1) {
                $("#add_content").attr('checked', true);
            } else {
                $("#add_content").attr('checked', false);
            }
            self.formHandler.load(data);
        },
        function (error) { },
        function () { }
    );
}
```

Comment: So you want the checking function to be bound to some event?  When else does the value of add_content change besides on page refresh?

Comment: this load function reads data first and when `add_content= 1` make checkbox checked without refreshing page .now checkbox is working but after I refresh the page

Comment: Have you tried using `prop` in place of `attr` here?

Comment: yeah...it did not work

Comment: have you tried specific comparison? your json is returning 1, but that no necessarily may be a bool valid comparison in Jquery. What if you place your condition like  if (data.add_content == 1) ... since it may be considered as int instead of bool

Comment: sorry, my original code using this comparison but checkbox cannot be checked until I refresh the page..I dont want to refresh the page

Comment: Please make sure that the variable `data` is a json object, for example: before the if statement you can write `data = JSON.parse(data);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code :

```
    if (data.add_content == 1) {
        $("#add_content").prop('checked', true); 
    } else {
        $("#add_content").prop('checked', false); 
    }
    self.formHandler.load(data);
```

To this :

```
    if (data.add_content == 1) {
        $("#add_content").attr("checked", "checked").closet(span).addClass("checked"); 
    } 
    self.formHandler.load(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line, just make sure you use `.prop()`

```
$("#add_content").prop('checked', data.add_content == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to use prop()
[Setting a boolean attribute with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940733/setting-a-boolean-attribute-with-jquery)

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
load: function (id) {
var self = this;

KeyWord.byId(
    id,
    function (data) {
        if (data.add_content == 1) {
            $("#add_content").prop('checked', true); 
        } else {
            $("#add_content").prop('checked', false); 
        }
        self.formHandler.load(data);
    },
    function (error) { },
    function () { }
    );
}
```