# attr("disabled", false) causing error in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, input, disabled-input

I have the following code in my ts file:

```
 $('input[type=hidden]').attr("disabled", false);
```

Code works but i am getting the following error:
Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number, attr: string) => string | number | void)'.

Comment: what is the html element that you are calling with $('input[type=hidden]')?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a boolean attribute with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940733/setting-a-boolean-attribute-with-jquery)

Comment: [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove attribute altogether.

```
 $('input[type=hidden]').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to pass `false` as string.

```
 $('input[type=hidden]').attr("disabled", "false");
```